# How to redirect back to the previous page after saving data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, redirect, save

Im new to laravel.
I'm creating this project and here, after i save my data, i want to return to my previous state.

```
public function storeData(Request $request){
    // dd($request->all());
    $this->validate($request,[
        'Province'=>'required',
        'District' => 'required|max:100|min:3',
        'Electrorate' => 'required|max:100|min:3',
        'PollingBooth' => 'required|max:100|min:3',
        'issueTitle' => 'required|max:160|min:3',
        'issueDetails'=>'required|max:500|min:30',
        'issueCategory'=>'required'
    ]);
            $pollingbooth = new pollingbooth;
    $pollingbooth->Province=$request->Province;
    $pollingbooth->District=$request->District;
    $pollingbooth->Electrorate=$request->Electrorate;
    $pollingbooth->PollingBooth=$request->PollingBooth;
    $pollingbooth->issueTitle=$request->issueTitle;
    $pollingbooth->issueDetails=$request->issueDetails;
    $pollingbooth->issueCategory=$request->issueCategory;
    $pollingbooth->save();

    $pollingBoothNames=pollingbooth::all();
    //  dd ($pollingBoothNames);
    return view('issues')->with('pollingBoothNamez',$pollingBoothNames);
    // return redirect()->back();

}
```

above is my code.  i tried

```
        return view('issues')->with('pollingBoothNamez',$pollingBoothNames)->redirect()->back();
```

but no luck. what should i do here?
Im having the same problem with updating a "Issue" as well.

Comment: `return redirect()->back();` will work. what happen for this?

Comment: This will work `return redirect()->back()->with(''pollingBoothNamez',$pollingBoothNames);`

Comment: Thank You both. 
@Dev we cant put 2 returns. that commented one was just to check whether the redirect works.

Comment: @STA your code worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work :

```
return redirect()->back()->with(''pollingBoothNamez', $pollingBoothNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply **call the route** like this `return redirect('home/dashboard');`

Answer (score 1):

```
return redirect()->back();
```

or

```
return Redirect::to('your-route-url');
```